# in SSRS, is there a way to have a query get variable data from custom code in the report?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I am working on a report created by someone else. In the query for the Dataset it has two variables: @Start_Date and @End_Date but when the report is run, it does not ask for those dates. In stead it asks for the Year and Quarter. In the code section of the report I can see custom code functions that convert Year and Quarter to the Start and End date but cannot find where those functions are called.

Is there a way in SSRS to call a function for a query and return that data and where do I find that function call?

Comment: Have a look at the parameter's default values, they may be being used there. If you need more help I suggest you share the report design, in particular the dataset(s) and parameters including hidden parameters. You could also look at the rdl code directly and search for the name of the function to see where it is used.

Comment: Thank you. I found the parameters under the Dataset Properties > Parameters and see that is where the functions are being called.

That brings up another question, I've looked but have been unsuccessful so far. Is there some site that explains the steps taken by SSRS when running a report? I assume it runs the query first before assembling to report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS reports are just xml reports. If you're using Visual Studio, just right-click the rdl file and select `View Code`. From there you can search for the function name to see where it's being used.